# How Can i read properties files which is located inside Web-app folder in grails 2.4.4

Tags: grails

i have created one folder as properties, its contains file in the name `config.properties` inside `web-app` folder,now i need to read this config.properties files in `datasource.groovy` for configuration purpose how can i read this one i tried lot like

```
def filePath = "/config.properties"
grails.config.locations =  ["classpath:$filePath",
"file:${baseDir}/config.properties",
"file:${baseDir}/WEB-INF/properties/config.properties",
"file:${basedir}/config.properties",
"file:${basedir}/WEB-INF/properties/config.properties"
]
```

but no luck,how can i read properties files which is located inside web-app folder?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which source directory the properties file is located in. For example, if it's `grails-app/conf/foo.properties` then the following should work

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:foo.properties"]
```

Comment: File is located in wep-app/WEB-INF/properties/config.properties

Comment: @naina I was asking in which *source* directory the file is located, i.e. how does it get included in the .war file?